# Проблема с шифрованием XOR

Tags: c++, c, шифрование

Помогите найти ошибку в коде, текст из файла шифруется, а вот с дешифровкой проблемы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
#include <cctype>

char XORing(char key, char input);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    if(argv[1][0] == '1'){ //шифровка

        FILE *input;
        FILE *shifr;
        input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        shifr = fopen("shifr.txt", "w");

        //Ввод ключа с клавиатуры
         char key[30];
        printf("Введите ключ: ");
        gets(key);
        int k = strlen(key);
        //перевод в нижний регистр
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
        }

        //подсчет кол-ва символов в input
        int inp = 0; //счетчик
        while(fgetc(input) != EOF){
            inp++;
        }

        //шифрование input посимвольно
        for(int i = 0; i < inp; i++){
            char c = fgetc(input);
            c = tolower(c);
            fputc(XORing(key[i%k], c), shifr);
        }

        fclose(input);
        fclose(shifr);

    }
    else if(argv[1][0] == '2'){ //дешифровка

        FILE *key;
        FILE *shifr;
        FILE *deshifr;
        key = fopen("key.txt", "r");
        shifr = fopen("shifr.txt", "r");
        deshifr = fopen("deshifr.txt", "w");

        //создаем массив символов для ключа
        char KeyArr[30];
        fgets(KeyArr, 30, key);
        int k = strlen(KeyArr);
        //перевод в нижний регистр
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            KeyArr[i] = tolower(KeyArr[i]);
        }

        //подсчет кол-ва символов в shifr
        int sh = 0; //счетчик
        while(fgetc(shifr) != EOF){
            sh++;
        }

        //дешифровка
        for(int i = 0; i < sh; i++){
             char c = fgetc(shifr);
            fputc(XORing(KeyArr[i%k], c), deshifr);
        }

        fclose(key);
        fclose(shifr);
        fclose(deshifr);
    }

    else{
        printf("Error: faulse value");
    }

    return 0;
}

char XORing(char key, char input){
    char c = input ^ key;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы обманываете? Без позиционирования на начало файла между циклами этот код ничего шифровать не будет. В этом виде код неработоспособен в принципе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, вы что-то выдумываете. Никакой шифровки текста из файла ваш код не выполняет и выполнять не может. У вас цикл подсчета количества входных символов упирается в конец файла и там навсегда и остается. Сам цикл шифрования, разумеется, читать файл не будет и шифровать ничего не будет.

Чтобы этот код мог что-то шифровать, необходимо как минимум сделать `rewind(input)` между циклами чтения. Или избавиться совсем от этого ненужного предварительного вычисления размера файла. (Зачем понадобился этот лишний проход по файлу?)

Во-вторых, функция `gets` не включает символ `'\n'` в прочитанную строку. Функция `fgets` *включает* символ `'\n'` в прочитанную строку, если он наличествует во входе.

Это может быть причиной того, почему внешне одинаковые ключи шифровки/дешифровки на самом деле отличаются. Если файл с ключом у вас содержит перевод строки после собственно значения ключа, то этот перевод строки прочитается как часть ключа. Символ `'\n'` в ключе будет активно участвовать в процессе расшифровки, в то время как на этапе шифровки его там не было. Понятно, что из-за этого все поедет вкривь и вкось.

Не забываете "убивать" ненужный `'\n'` в конце строки

```
    char KeyArr[30];
    fgets(KeyArr, sizeof KeyArr, key);
    KeyArr[strcspn(KeyArr, "\n")] = 0;
```

В-третьих, использование типа `char`, который может быть знаковым, для выполнения  побитовых операций - не самая лучшая идея.

**P.S.** Функция `gets` официально исключена из состава стандартной библиотеки. Пользуйтесь `scanf` или `fgets` и там, и там.

Comment: А что не так со знаковым xor'ом?

Comment: XOR работает без проблем, просто это правило хорошего тона: работаешь с битовыми полями, используй беззнаковые типы. Завтра сдвиги понадобятся, а знак там в 99% случаев только мешает.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну хотя бы то, что операнды XOR будут повергаться integer promotions в тип `int`, то есть для знакового `char` будет проводиться расширение знака. Например если взять `signed char c = -128` (`0x80` в битовом представлении) и выполнить `c ^ 0x80` то в результате получится отнюдь не `0`, а `-256` (`0xffffff00`). Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Во-первых, вроде неправда? А во-вторых, оно же всё равно обратно урежется, как бы ни расширялось. UPDATE: http://ideone.com/leGGiC

Comment: @Qwertiy: Во-первых, правда: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd3b102e4613fcdc. Вы же просто взяли частный пример, в котором обе стороны одинаково расширились. Во-вторых, в вопросе ТС результат передается в `fputc`, у котрого аргумент `int`, т.е. ничего не урезается (да, `fputc` внутри себя урезает, но в какой-нибудь другой функции запосто может быть сюрприз). В-третьих, язык жестко определяет только беззнаковые урезания. Знаковые урезания - implementation-defined, т.е. в общем случае непортабельны.

Comment: `char XORing(char key, char input);` - у него будет именно та ситуация, которую я взял: два char'а одинаково расширились (даже если это implementation defined, в чём я не очень уверен, а потом ещё и результат до char'а обрезался.